# Ubuntu 20.04 crashes randomly (Intel i9-9900K, Nvidia 3090)

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, google-chrome, crash

My pc was randomly crashing . Everything is fine in Win10. What is wrong with this setup? I don't want to use intel's gpu

[image: ubuntu]
[image: nvidia]
[image: nvidia]
[image: nvidia]
[image: nvidia]
[image: logs]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was, XMP was set to `auto` in BIOS. I changed it to `II`, and stopped crashing.